# Postfix can not send from Mydomain - only to third party domains

Tags: postfix, sendmail

So I have setup an Ubuntu server and want to use postfix in order to sendmail via php.

**The server host: example.com**

When the server sends an email to anything@example.com, I get an error. If sending to any other address (someone@anotherdomain.com), it works fine.

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = example.com, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated 
defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

**When I send mail via php to example.com addresses I get the following error:**

```
exception 'Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException' with message '5.1.1 <support@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

**When I send mail via php to AnyOtherDomain.com there is NO ERROR:**

The actual mail for example.com is handled by a third party server. All SPF / DKIM records are in place so sending works fine so long as it is to third party domains.

Obviously this is a setting, which one I am still working to figure out.

**EDIT:**

Digging into the mail logs I note this:

```
Apr  6 13:37:57 somename postfix/local[25416]: 3625CE2EB7: to=<support@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=undeliverable (unknown user: "support")
Apr  6 13:42:29 xxxxx postfix/smtpd[25501]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  6 13:42:29 xxxxx postfix/smtpd[25501]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <support@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<no-reply@example.com> to=<support@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
Apr  6 13:42:29 xxxxx postfix/smtpd[25501]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

So I believe the server is trying to send to a user rather than an email address...

Comment: Could you fix the output of postconf -n? Also, seems that you are using Zendmail for something. Could you elaborate? The message basically means that you are using a local table or `local_recipient_maps`

Comment: Updated formatting - the zend stuff uses SendMail(). If the email used is: support@example.com it dies, if customer@gmail.com is used, it works fine.

Comment: Does the user getting the mail exist?  The solution might be as simple as adding `support: root` to `/etc/aliases`.

Comment: The user does not exist. Not a solution to add a user for each mail address.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was not working was because I had set:

MyDomains to include example.com

From the [manual](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination)

> The mydestination parameter specifies what domains this machine will
>   deliver locally, instead of forwarding to another machine. The default
>   is to receive mail for the machine itself.

This line was the culprit:

```
mydestination = example.com, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
```

Updated it to:

```
localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

Basically, PostFix was attempting to handle all mail at Example.com instead of sending it off.